# C++ XInput and XBOX 360 controller never connects

Tags: c++, qt, xbox360, xinput

I'm trying to connect an XBOX 360 controller to get input for a program, but my program will never register a connected controller -- I have confirmed the controller is connected.

I'm running **Windows**, programming in **C++**, and using **QT** for my IDE. My code is just from: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/26949/xbox-controller-input-in-c-with-xinput

The only code I did not use from that site are the includes. My includes are just:

> ```
> #include <Windows.h>
> #include <Xinput.h>
> ```

and my Xinput lib is included in my .pro as:

> win32: LIBS += -lXinput9_1_0

When I run the code, the program never connects to my controller.

Is there something I am missing or that I have messed up?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after spending a considerable amount of time searching and reading I reexamined my code and found that I never assigned a player number.

> XBOXController* Player1 = new XBOXController(1);

where my bad code was just:

> XBOXController* Player1 = new XBOXController;

Yay simple fixes.